# How to use npm warnings in tslint?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, eslint, tslint

I am new using tslint, in the past I used eslint for javascript files and now I want to use tslint as my typescript linting tool.

The thing is that using eslint I was able to specify that some of my errors where specifyed as NPM warnings, in this case the console logging.

[image: **Console error using tsling**]

As you can see my "warnings" are throwing an npm ERR, is there a way to tell that it should be npm WARN ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the severity of the rule an object must be used as the rule setting.

```
{
  // ...
  "rules": {
    "no-console": {
      "options": [true, "log"],
      "severity": "warning"
    }
  }
}
```

You may also wish to follow this [link to the documentation](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/configuration/).

Comment: Ok, thanks I was using this reference:  https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-console/

Comment: Ah, I see how that could easily be misunderstood. As I'm sure you know now the "error" string is referring to the function `console.error()`.

Comment: Sure, now I it is refering to the console methods not to the console itself. Btw do you know any way to make the output prettier, like coloring or changing the warning for npm warn!  `WARNING: src/server.ts[3, 1]: Calls to 'console.log' are not allowed.`

Comment: @FAYA you can use the `-t stylish` option to get the prettier colors. https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/cli/